# Message boxs are not working as expected

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I have 2 text boxes that accept input. The data is calculated and displayed in a `ListBox`.

I was not getting the message boxes to show at all. So I unnested everything and now they are displaying no matter what data I put in. The funny thing is the calculations are correct and display correctly.

I need the message boxes to appear if the data in the two text boxes are not a number, are empty or are less than zero.

Please if anyone can give me an idea I would be grateful.

```
' Did user enter a numeric value?
If IsNumeric(txtHourlyWage.Text) Then
    decHourlyWage = Convert.ToDecimal(txtHourlyWage.Text)
End If

' Is Hourly Wage greather than zero?
If decHourlyWage > 0 Then
End If

' Did user enter a numeric value?
If IsNumeric(txtExpectedRaise.Text) Then
    decExpectedRaise = Convert.ToDecimal(txtExpectedRaise.Text)
End If

' Did user enter a numeric value?
If decExpectedRaise > 0 Then
End If

' If txtHourlyWage.Text = "" Or txtExpectedRaise.Text = "" Then
'MsgBox("Input Cannot Be Empty")

iNextyear = (decHourlyWage * decHoursInWeek) * (decWeeksInYear)

iNextyear = iNextyear
decAnnualPay = iNextyear
lstAnnualPay.Items.Add(decAnnualPay.ToString("c"))

For intNumber = 1 To 9
  '   Body of Loop
  iNextyear = iNextyear + iNextyear * CDec((txtExpectedRaise.Text)) / 100
  decAnnualPay = iNextyear
  lstAnnualPay.Items.Add(decAnnualPay.ToString("c"))
Next

' Display error message if user entered a negative number
MsgBox("You Entered " & txtHourlyWage.ToString() & ". Please Enter a Positive Number ", , "question")

MsgBox("You Entered " & txtExpectedRaise.ToString() & ". Please Enter a Positive Number ", , "question")


'Display error message if user entered a nonnumeric value
MsgBox("Please Enter A Number ", , "question")
txtHourlyWage.Text = ""
txtHourlyWage.Focus()

MsgBox("Please Enter A Number ", , "question")
txtExpectedRaise.Text = ""
txtExpectedRaise.Focus()
btnCompute.Visible = False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the more powerfull [decimal.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9zbda557(v=vs.110).aspx) in this way

```
'  Did user enter a numeric value?
If Not decimal.TryParse(txtHourlyWage.Text, decHourlyWage) OrElse _
                        decHourlyWage < 0 Then
   MsgBox("You Entered an invalid value for the Hourly Wage (negative, zero or empty", "Number")
   return
 End If
```

The same pattern applies to the other values.

Comment: OMG,  you are amazing.  it works. I owe you so much.  I wish I could do something for you.  Thank you very very much